# API error: 500, "this error has been logged" when retrieving questions

Tags: support

I am using the following URL to get new questions:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?pagesize=100&page=1&fromdate=1423639578&site=stackoverflow&key=MY_KEY_HERE
```

I get:

```
"has_more":true
```

in response, so I use the next URL:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?pagesize=100&page=2&fromdate=1423639578&site=stackoverflow&key=MY_KEY_HERE
```

but I get the error:

```
{ "error_id":500,"error_message":"this error has been logged","error_name":"internal_error"  }
```

Why ?

**Update:** in the future the send link will work correctly, but I can reproduce the error by increasing the PAGE parameter and analyze "has_more" in response.